# How to sort non-uniform strings that contain numeric values?

Tags: c#, .net, gridview-sorting

I'm having some trouble getting a GridView column of strings to sort properly.

The type of values in the column look like: $99,999, $200, /500, /50,000

Basically non-decimal currency values that **may** have a '/' instead of a '$'

Does anyone have a good approach to sorting these?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#.NET - " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: How do you want the values sorted?  Should all the currency values come first and then the non-currency values come second, or should the sort function ignore the $ and / and simply sort by the numbers, or something else?

Comment: I would like the values to sort from greatest to least and vice-versa. The '/' and '$' don't matter.

Comment: My first idea would be a regex to find the first `[0-9,]*`, remove `,` from its result with `.Replace(",","")` and finally `decimal.Parse`(with the culture you need). But without a clear specification of what values you expect, and how to sort them, it's hard to answer this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a sort function that takes a set of strings, removes the first character, then sorts as normal. This would remove the $ or / issue.

To elaborate: create a new [iComparer](http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2005/03/06/implementing-icomparer-for-sorting-custom-objects/), and then have it return whether string1.SubString[1] > string2.SubString[1]. I'd write a bit of code, but I'm currently away from a computer with VS or Mono on it.

Comment: Appreciate your help, currently taking a swing at this.

Answer (score 0):

Realized I can just set the sort expression of the BoundField to a different hidden column on the gridview (which contains the amount in a uniform itemCD string). Doh!